# Mocking a function call within a function in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

This is my first time building out unit tests, and I'm not quite sure how to proceed here. Here's the function I'd like to test; it's a method in a class that accepts one argument, *url*, and returns one string, *task_id*:

```
def url_request(self, url):
    conn = self.endpoint_request()
    authorization = conn.authorization

    response = requests.get(url, authorization)

    return response["task_id"]
```

The method starts out by calling another method within the same class to obtain a token to connect to an API endpoint. Should I be mocking the output of that call (*self.endpoint_request()*)?

If I do have to mock it, and my test function looks like this, how do I pass a fake token/auth endpoint_request response?

```
@patch("common.DataGetter.endpoint_request")
def test_url_request(mock_endpoint_request):
    mock_endpoint_request.return_value = {"Auth": "123456"}

    # How do I pass the fake token/auth to this?
    task_id = DataGetter.url_request(url)
```

Comment: Usually it's better to set your test boundaries at the class level - so, no, you would not mock the `self.endpoint_request()`, but you would mock any external calls that the call might be making.

Comment: @rdas - Thanks, but what do you mean by setting test boundaries at the class level? Should I move the endpoint_request() call outside of this function?

Comment: Test once class at a time - mock everything that is external to that class. That unit test would be meant for testing only the logic in that class.

Comment: Just like `url_request` is using `requests.get` (which you would mock), `endpoint_request` is likely doing something similar to produce *its* return value. You will probably want to mock whatever *that* is so that `endpoint_request` can execute without, e.g., using the network.

Comment: That said, it *might* be more reasonable to have the authorization be an additional argument to `url_request`, so that you can test `url_request` without having to worry about `endpoint_request`. Whoever *calls* `url_request` would be responsible for getting the correct authorization. (And this makes more sense if the same authorization can be used for multiple requests.)

Comment: The problem is that if `endpoint_request` is *also* using `requests.get`, you have to be careful to mock that function so that consecutive calls return two different things. I, at least, would like to see the definition of `endpoint_request` before posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have shown is strongly dominated by interactions.  Which means that there will most likely be no bugs to find with unit-testing: The potential bugs are on the interaction level: You access `conn.authorization` - but, is this the proper member?  And, does it already have the proper representation in the way you need it further on?  Is `requests.get` the right method for the job?  Is the argument order as you expect it?  Is the return value as you expect it?  Is `task_id` spelled correctly?

These are (some of) the potential bugs in your code.  But, with unit-testing you will not be able to find them: When you replace the depended-on components with some mocks (which you create or configure), your unit-tests will just succeed: Lets assume that you have a misconception about the return value of `requests.get`, namely that `task_id` is spelled wrongly and should rather be spelled `taskId`.  If you mock `requests.get`, you would implement the mock based on your own misconception.  That is, your mock would return a map with the (misspelled) key `task_id`.  Then, the unit-test would succeed despite of the bug.

You will only find that bug with integration testing, where you bring your component and depended-on components together.  Only then you can test the assumptions made in your component against the reality of the other components.